# How to get login and logout time in windows in python?

Tags: python, windows, authentication, logout

I've tried the following code but I'm not able to get the desired output (time format)

```
import win32com.client
import time

strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer, "root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")


def Convert_to_human_time(dtmDate):

    strDateTime = ""

    if dtmDate[4] == 0:
        strDateTime = dtmDate[5] + '/'

    else:
        strDateTime = dtmDate[4] + dtmDate[5] + '/'

    if dtmDate[6] == 0:
        strDateTime = strDateTime + dtmDate[7] + '/'

    else:
        strDateTime = strDateTime + dtmDate[6] + dtmDate[7] + '/'
        strDateTime = strDateTime + dtmDate[0] + dtmDate[1] + dtmDate[2] + dtmDate[3] + " " + \
            dtmDate[8] + dtmDate[9] + ":" + dtmDate[10] + \
            dtmDate[11] + ':' + dtmDate[12] + dtmDate[13]

    return strDateTime


for objItem in colItems:

    if objItem.Name is not None:
        print("Name: " + str(objItem.Name))

    if objItem.LastLogon is not None:
        print("Last Logon (Normal Format): " + str((objItem.LastLogon)))
        print("Last Logon (Human Readable Format): " +
              Convert_to_human_time(objItem.LastLogon))

    if objItem.LastLogoff is not None:
        print("Last Logoff (Normal Format): " + str(objItem.LastLogoff))
        print("Last Logoff (Human Readable Format): " +
              Convert_to_human_time(objItem.LastLogoff))

    if objItem.LogonHours is not None:
        print("Logon Hours: " + str(objItem.LogonHours))

    if objItem.LogonServer is not None:
        print("Logon Server: " + str(objItem.LogonServer))

    if objItem.NumberOfLogons is not None:
        print("Number Of Logons: " + str(objItem.NumberOfLogons))
```

The output I'm getting is of the form:

```
Last Logon (Normal Format): **************.******+***
Last Logon (Human Readable Format): **/**/**** **:**:**
Last Logoff (Normal Format): **************.******+***
Last Logoff (Human Readable Format): **/**/**** **:**:**
Logon Hours: Sunday: No Limit -- Monday: No Limit -- Tuesday: No Limit -- Wednesday: No Limit -- Thursday: No Limit -- Friday: No Limit -- Saturday: No Limit
Logon Server: \\*
Number Of Logons: 0
```

I'm trying to calculate the number of hours a user spent on the windows system, for that I need login and logout time of a user. The output is not in the date-time format. Please let me know how to get the output in the form of date and time.
Thank you

Comment: "The output is not in the date-time format" - be a bit more specific with an example of you want converting, currently you're showing two different formats with all the numbers stripped

Comment: That is literally how I'm getting the output all the numbers stripped